# Purpose of op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

There is voltage input before the R3 resistor. The single-output of this op-amp is to the right of the right-most node in the schematic attached below. I understand that the 5V input and capacitor C7 before the non-inverting terminal serves as a 5V DC bias and a decoupling capacitor respectively. What does the presence of resistor R7 and capacitor C4 do to this op amp? Specifically, what type of op-amp would this be considered as?

Comment: It's a 2nd order low pass filter. The 5V is not accomplishing DC bias - C7 should just be grounded.

Comment: @td127 5V is as good as ground for AC (assuming the supply is decently decoupled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation of the ["Sallen-Key" topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sallen%E2%80%93Key_topology), which uses an opamp to produce a second order filter response.

In this particular arrangement the behaviour is "low-pass", meaning that frequency components of the input signal below some "cut-off" point will pass from input to output unattenuated, but components beyond the cut-off frequency will be attenuated at a rate of "12dB per octave". This rate is called the "roll-off".

This particular Sallen-Key system produces a 2nd order roll-off. First order roll-off refers to "6dB per octave". 2nd order would mean a roll-off of 12dB per octave, 3rd being 18dB and so on. Each 6dB represents a "factor of 2", so 12db means a factor of \$2^2=4\$, 18dB being a factor of \$2^3=8\$. The term "octave" refers to a doubling of frequency.

So for a 2nd order filter like this, with a roll-off of 12dB per octave, we can say that the voltage amplitude of frequency components beyond the cut-off frequency of the filter will be diminished by a factor of 4 (one quarter) for each doubling of frequency.

I simulated the circuit you showed, which has this frequency response:

[image]

We define the cut-off frequency to be the point where the attenuation is 3dB, corresponding to a reduction of amplitude to 70%. From this graph you can see this occurs for components at about 18kHz.

Above this frequency, you see the roll-off, at a rate of 12dB for each doubling of frequency. The gain is exactly 0dB (100%, or 1) for all frequency components well below the cut-off frequency.

Answer (score 2):

This is a second-order unity-gain Sallen-Key low pass filter. The fact that C7 is connected to 5V is immaterial, it could also be (and usually is) connected to GND.

More here: https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-222.pdf

Comment: Then C7 is still a decoupling capacitor?

Comment: Nope. It’s part of the filter network.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a short and intuitive explanation of the working principle is helpful?

- When you disconnect the most right node of C4 from the circuit and connect it with ground potential, you have two simple RC-sections in series. Hence, you have a simple second-order lowpass - and at its output there is a unity gain buffer which provides a low-resistive voltage output.
- However, this simple lowpass has rather pure selection properties. The so-called Q-value (pole Q) of the circuit is always below 0.5 (Qp<0.5). Remember that a Butterworth response needs a value Qp=0.7071.
- The "trick" of the shown topology is the following: The passive second-order lowpass is transferred to an active second-order circuit by providing positive feedback to the circuit by lifting the ground connection of C4 and connect it to the opamp output.

- This active filter circuit now allows higher values of Qp, which means: The magnitude response in the cut-off region is enhanced and thus allows other lowpass functions like Butterworth, Chebyshev,..

- It is possible to use a fixed low-gain stage instead of a unity-gain buffer. In this case, the design formulas have to be modified, of course. Such a modification (for example gain A=2) will result in parts values which are more convenient.